# Excel chart axis date format in Spanish, months without dot

Tags: excel, date, charts, format, axis-labels

I am trying to change the format of an Excel chart axis. The language must be Spanish, and I obtain the following:

```
 mar.-18    jun.-18    sep.-18    dic.-18
```

But I would like to have

```
mar-18    jun-18    sep-18    dic-18
```

I need to keep the axis as date-axis (not text). Any chance I can eliminate the "dot" from the date format?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your Data starts in `A1`. This formula will replace the "." with nothing so the period will no longer pull into the chart.

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")`

Then just copy the result from this formula over the original data and delete the formula.

Comment: Cell format is daily data, like 01/10/2018. I don't want to change cell data, but axis format.

Comment: @Javi can you share the format code, so I can adjust it? It should look something like this "mmm.-yy"

Comment: Current format code is     [$-C0A]mmm-aa;  Where "aa" is the thing that we use in Spanish for "yy".